# Como corrigir o erro no Log?

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, struts2

Estou a usar Struts 2 no Tomcat, e consigo correr o código. Contudo, estou a ter esse erro no log.

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet

E não faço ideia do que seja. Já andei a pesquisar e não consegui encontrar ainda a solução. Podem ajudar-me, por favor?

Comment: Qual seria o erro?

Comment: O erro que me dá é: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet

Comment: @Iris Poderia postar o stack trace completo? (o local onde mostra os erros detalhadamente) E se o stack trace indicar uma linha do seu código poderia postar tb o trecho do código em que está o problema?

Comment: Você colocou as Lib do Struts 2 na pasta correta?(Web-Inf/lib)

Comment: Iris, Bem-vindo(a) ao Stack Overflow em Português! Como pode ser subentendido pelo comentário do @adelmo00, o problema pode ser causado pela falta das bibliotecas (Jars) do Struts no diretório `lib` da aplicação. Você poderia editar sua pergunta e adicionar a lista de bibliotecas presentes na sua pasta `WEB-INF/lib`?

Answer (score 1):

O seu problema realmente deve ser a falta da biblioteca do struts no libpath do seu projeto:
se estiver utilizando maven em seu projeto adicione a seguinte dependencia no pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.10</version>
</dependency>
```

ou caso contrário importe ela no classpath pelo eclipse, o jar encontra-se no seguinte link.
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/struts/struts-core/1.3.10/struts-core-1.3.10.jar